# How do I do 1 million Max calculations each a 100 row range with results written in new column?

Tags: mysql, max

So I have 1 column and 1 million rows of data. I need to calculate the maximum value for rows 1-100, then 2-101, 3-102, all the way to a million rows. And the results get written in an empty column next to this one. So the maximum number for rows 1-100 will be in row 1, column2. And the maximum number for rows 2-101 gets written in row 2, column 2. And so on.

I'm coming from excel where doing this kind of stuff is extremely easy. However the amount of stuff I need to do is way too much for excel. I was told mysql would be a good choice for this kind of stuff. And sorry if it seems I have done no research at all, I am buried in it right now but I'm still having trouble pulling multiple concepts together to get my stuff figured out so pointers would be welcome. This is just a fraction of what I need/want to do unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is **NOT** a spreadsheet and you should not try to use it as if it were. You need to totally rethink your algorithm and adapt it to work in a database.

For this situation you need to add a column to define the order for your rows. After you change your data model, your query might like something like this (won't work in MySQL though unfortunately, as it doesn't have support for analytical functions):

```
SELECT MAX(col) OVER (
    ORDER BY id
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 99 FOLLOWING
) AS running_maximum
FROM table1
```

But first you're going to need to add an `id` column to your table. Without that, your rows have no well-defined order and talking about rows "1-100" does not make sense because (unlike in Excel) in MySQL rows don't have any row numbers associated with them unless you add a column for that purpose.

Comment: +1 - MySQL does not implicitly care about ordering of rows, and it's not a good fit if you care about ordering of rows.

Comment: Well if that is something obvious then I will need to learn more about this. But so you know I will then need to use that data with the other data though. So things just fragment more and more for no reason? I don't see what is wrong with putting the data in a new field?

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer! And the code. This helps me to understand mysql better.

Comment: Alright so I just tested this and got the code running! I was using 3 million rows and it took just 8 seconds. However, I'm only getting 30,000 results back. Which means its only using each row once. Instead of incrementing by 1 row each time, it is doing it by 100 rows. So I will look into this myself now, but if you have a solution you are welcome to help :) So like I explained earlier, the ranges will change by one row. So 1-100, 2-101, 3-102, ect. Thanks.

Comment: @user1463899: Ohhh, sorry I misread the question - you want a *running* maximum. I thought you wanted a maximum per group. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have the analytical functions that you'd need to make this easy (and fast) to do in SQL. Can you use a better database or are you stuck with MySQL? And for a running maximum, it would make some sense to store it in the same table, if you still want to use that approach.

Comment: No problem! I'm not stuck with mysql or even using a database. I was just recommended to use a database earlier. Maybe another option would be using a csv / text file and editing it via a programming language?

Comment: @user1463899: MySQL is totally unsuitable for this. Oracle, PostgreSQL or SQL Server 2012 I think would all work. But you could also just store the data in a text file and use a scripting language (e.g. Python) to write a small program to crunch the numbers. It really depends on what you need to do. I guess that this is only the first step in a larger algorithm and I think you should only use a database if each step in your algorithm can be expressed easily in SQL. Can you link to where someone suggested to use a database?

Comment: I think I will go the scripting language / text file route. Learning to do simple stuff like that will benefit me in the future. Well at least it sounds simple. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hey Mark, I was thinking if you could give me an overview of what would be needed with any scripting language. Lets say I start with my original data in a text file, 1 number in each row. Would I be able to make python read the first 100 lines, perform max calculation, write to file, and then move down a row via some loop type thing?

Comment: @user1463899: Yes - you can read lines one at a time and store them in  a queue. When the queue is full (100 lines) you remove old lines before adding new ones. You can either recalculate the maximum each step, or you can update it only when necessary. Sorry but what you are asking is too big a question to go into more details in the comments section of another question.